# How to change the header of a table row

Tags: c#, gridview, tablerow

I have this piece of code. i want to display the text of the header as below. But instead it turns the whole column of data to "Social Security Number".
I mean the header should display the name in the formatted way.

Here is the code:

```
foreach (TableRow row in gvPatientList.Controls[0].Controls)
{
    row.Cells[7].Text = "Social Security Number";
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: how are you declaring your table?

Comment: I am getting a list of values that needs to be binded in the grid view and exported to excel.hence customization is required,the value ssn needs to be declared as social security number.

Comment: How are you populating the gridview show us that code.. also how are you defining the columns for the gridview.. are they set to `Auto Generate`? can you show the aspx code for how the social security column is defined.. you need to provide us with all relevant code.. also what you are trying to do is quite simple I posted an example but without seeing how you are populating the DataTable etc...then you are  leaving us in the dark also do a check in that foreach loop that `if row.Cells.Text = "ssn"`  then set it to `Social Security Number` and breakout of the loop

Comment: I am deleting my answer until you update the original question and show us how the gridvie is being bound to the data source

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you want to rename a column header, not to change the text of the cells. So, this might be the solution:

```
gvPatientList.Columns[7].ColumnName = "Social Security Number";
```